# filter partial data from mysql table

Tags: mysql

Let's suppose I have this data stored in a table:

- h
- he
- hel
- hell
- hello
- w
- wo
- wor
- worl
- world
  Given That I don't know what is the content of the table,how can I get just "hello" and "word" from a mysql query?
  In other words I should filter out all the "partial" words and get only the ones not contained in others.
  Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you only want complete , ie in a UK dictionary, words - if so you need a dictionary to compare the tokens to. NB consider war and warm and warmest all are valid words. Or are you looking for a spellchecker?

Comment: In this case only warmest should be returned since warm is part of it

Answer (score 0):

You may try following one:

`SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE UPPER (COLUMN_NAME) IN (UPPER ('hello'), UPPER ('world'));`

Output:

hello
world

Comment: Thanks for your answer, anyway this will work only if the contained words "hello" and "word" are already known. I edited the question to make it more clear.